# Regex on Zabbix API?

Tags: json, regex, zabbix

After some hours spent reading Zabbix Api's documentation, I haven't found a way of doing a `search` by key with more than one possible value.

So, with this code:

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"method": "item.get",
"params": {
    "output": "extend",
    "hostids": " 10355",
    "search": {
        "key_": "[in_*|out_*]"
     },

"sortfield": "name"
},
"auth": "15729708df1f5936f6ea840ae1b41cb6",
"id": 0
}
```

I'm trying to get every `item` which key is `in_<anything>` **OR** `out_<anything>` so, the output would be the combination of all the items related to the interfaces. Instead, I get this:

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[],"id":0}`

I know that there's the possibility to use `filter` instead of `search` but, from what I read, it is used when you want exact match, which is not the case.

Comment: Try `"key_": "(in|out)_.*"` if regex is supported at all here.

Comment: Nope, nothing. And regex is supported as it is for json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zabbix API (and filtering in other places) does not support regexp. In some versions you could pass wildcards, but that won't solve your current issue. You will have to do two separate API queries.

To answer the question in the comment here, search can be negated with the `excludeSearch` parameter - see the [API documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/api/reference_commentary) for more detail.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info, do you know if there's any way of filtering by *non matching* instead?

Comment: Edited the answer to include that info, although it's best to keep one question to one topic.

Answer (score 1):

To this work you need put this key ***searchWildcardsEnabled***

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"method": "item.get",
"params": {
    "output": "extend",
    "hostids": " 10355",
    "searchWildcardsEnabled": "true",
    "search": {
        "key_": "[in_*|out_*]"
     },

"sortfield": "name"
},
"auth": "15729708df1f5936f6ea840ae1b41cb6",
"id": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider using the `searchByAny` [parameter](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/api/reference_commentary#common_get_method_parameters) that let's you find items that matchs any of the `search` criteria. Here is the correct json that you should try :

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "item.get",
    "params": {
        "output": "extend",
        "hostids": " 10355",
        "searchWildcardsEnabled": "true",
        "search": {
            "key_": [
                "in_*",
                "out_*"
            ]
        },
        "sortfield": "name"
    },
    "auth": "15729708df1f5936f6ea840ae1b41cb6",
    "id": 1
}
```